# How I can compare datetime datatype with string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to compare datetime datatype, like "20/12/2011 00:00:00", with compound string date format (I mean that it is composed of string of date, string of month and string of year).

For example, coloumn entime is datatime datatype which is stored "20/12/2011 00:00:00" data and other three column(date,month,year respectively) are string. so I want to compare between entime column with the date,month and year composed together, How I can write SQL Command to suppurt the above requirement ?

Hope you can help me ?

Comment: Hint: cast one data type to the other.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to convert the datetime to string and then make the needed comparisons.

You can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) how to make the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the DATEPART function as an alternative.

```
SELECT * 
FROM DateTable 
WHERE 
DATEPART(YEAR, [DATECOLUMN]) = @YearString
AND DATEPART(MONTH, [DATECOLUMN]) = @MonthString
AND DATEPART(DAY, [DATECOLUMN]) = @DayString
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go below way, would you please try it out, thanks

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), GETDATE(), 105) AS DATETIME)
SELECT CAST(('20'+'-'+'12'+'-'+'2011') AS DATETIME)
```

As an example:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), yourDateColumn, 105) AS DATETIME) FROM TableName

SELECT CAST((dayColumn+'-'+monthColumn+'-'+yearColumn) AS DATETIME) 
     FROM anotherTable
```

Finally the comparison:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tableName t1, anotherTable t2
WHERE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), t1.DateColumnName, 105) AS DATETIME) 
    = CAST((t2.dayColumn+'-'+t2.monthColumn+'-'+t2.yearColumn) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this your requirement ?

```
DECLARE @tblTemp TABLE
(
    DAY VARCHAR(10)
    ,Month VARCHAR(10)
    ,Year VARCHAR(10)
)
DECLARE @dtDateTime VARCHAR(10) = '20/12/2011 00:00:00'

INSERT INTO @tblTemp VALUES
('01','01','2011'),
('01','02','2011'),
('01','03','2011'),
('01','04','2012');

select * from @tblTemp where CONVERT(DATE,Year +Month+DAY ,103) <  CONVERT(DATE,@dtDateTime,103)
```